# How data stored in Binary form?

Tags: binary

I want to know the concept of data That how data is stored in a computer system in binary form. There is huge amount of data and how many combinations computer system make to store that data.

Comment: This question is too broad and there is plenty information on the internet. Just start googling and you will find answers.

Comment: @FCin Actually i want precise and short answer

Comment: You can't get a precise and short answer to a broad and vague question. Please narrow it down and explain better what you want the answer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary is as the name suggests, only two points that are expressed in a number of ways depending on where you look but all represent the same meaning: -

`1` or `0`

`1` or `-1`

`+` or `-`

`up` or `down`

`on` or `off`

A computer does nothing more than put all them together very fast to make things, similar to Morse code. In Morse code a series of `on` and `off` makes up letters, letters make up words, sentences, paragraphs, chapters, books, libraries.

How is the data stored, its nothing more than binary, a piece of metal that is magnetized (or switched) to be `+` or `-` to represent one of the binary choices.

This was not the right question for this site and you should have searched and read up on this yourself.